# How do I use a subquery in an insert() command through my ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm doing the following to insert information into the database:

```
ContentValues attachTags = new ContentValues();
attachTags.put("word_fk", "SELECT id FROM entry WHERE ent_seq = " + String.valueOf(line).substring(1));
attachTags.put("tag_id", gTagID);

// Insert the record
Uri insertUri = contentProvider.insert(Uri.parse(mContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + mContentProvider.PATH_SET_TAGS_ON_WORD), attachTags);
```

Unfortunately, **word_fk** is literally set to **SELECT id FROM entry WHERE ent_seq = 1157170**, like so:

```
id  |   word_fk                                         |   tag_id
52      SELECT id FROM entry WHERE ent_seq = 1157170        4
```

I intended for **word_fk** to be set to whatever is returned from the subquery, but it seems as though `insert()` doesn't execute subqueries when it inserts information into a database. I guess it's related to SQL input sanitization? In any case, how do I make this insert() query work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I intended for word_fk to be set to whatever is returned from the
>   subquery, but it seems as though insert() doesn't execute subqueries
>   when it inserts information into a database. I guess it's related to
>   SQL input sanitization?

A `ContentValues` object is a simple map between some columns and the values, so you can't really use it to make sub queries, the data is used as it is.

However, it seems you control the `ContentProvider` so I don't see why you can't simply extract the sub-query from the `ContentValues` passed in the `insert()` method from the `word_fk` key and further use it directly to obtain what you want. Another approach would be to require that the `Uri` passed to the `insert()` method of the provider must contain an additional identifier(the `ent_seq` parameter in your example) if the `word_fk` is present in the `ContentValues` used.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. I can add a special character to the front of `line` to indicate that it needs to be run through the subquery. If insert() detects that special character, then it'll know to run the subquery first and update the ContentValue accordingly before inserting the values to the database.